# Pandas dataframe not working when it contains column called "name"

Tags: python, mysql, pandas

I am using Sakila database for a project and when I am trying to load all tables from MySql as pandas data frames, the tables language and category fail. The reason why that happens seems to be related to the fact that they both contain a column called "name". If I change it to anything else then they work correctly. Am I doing something wrong or is this an actual thing?

Screenshots below:

When loading the table as is (you can see for the name column I get sakila.category for some reason):

```
pandas_df = pd.DataFrame(numpy_data, columns=current_table.columns)
```

[image]

When I change the column name(I just put it with capital N):

```
pandas_df = pd.DataFrame(numpy_data, columns=['category_id', 'Name', 'last_update'])
```

[image]

It is not something related to the code as if I run something like:

```
pandas_df = pd.DataFrame(numpy_data, columns=['category_id', 'name', 'last_update'])
```

It will still fail because of the column named "name".

EDIT: I think it is because a pandas dataframe has an attribute called name, like `pd.name` and because there is a column called "name" it breaks it.

Comment: show us your code as well and avoid using screenshots

Comment: @eshirvana I added the two lines of code that are relevant. Let me know if there is anything else that would be relevant.